# Highcharts doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, highcharts

I have a ruby on rails app that uses highcharts.

Locally it works like a charm, however when I push the app to Heroku, Highcharts stops working and the `div` tag that is supposed to contain the chart appears empty.
I even tested it with one of the Highcharts examples (which has only hardcoded data), and still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: The problem was in the precompiling of assets. Turned out that highcharts was not precompiled

Added :

config.assets.precompile += ['rollover.js', 'highcharts.js']
to production.rb (i suppose application.rb should work as well)

and

to layout file.

(since i expected all javascript files gets compiled in application.jss i only had  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>  in my layout file)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Highcharts is not loading - either because it isn't being pushed to Heroku or because it isn't being served properly.  Go to the URL where highcharts.js *should* be and see if you get the JavaScript or a 404.

If you *can* reach highcharts.js without issue then the problem is most likely in the setup code.  Check and see if the appropriate variables are loaded onto the page (using the web developer tools for the browser you are testing in) and if there are any JavaScript errors showing up when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Sean, highcharts.js  is not available but i think it's OK, since i precompiled the assets so i just have "application.js". can precompile cause this issue?
How can i make sure that precomiple worked fine? I'm using rake assets:precompile to do it.

i overruled the issues related to setup after a sample chart with hardcoded data failed to work. i think you are right and the issue is indeed in the js not in the setup

Comment: Highcharts has a dependency on jQuery. Does your precompilation take care of this dependency?

Comment: Thanks,Figured it out turned out that Highcharts wasn't precompiled properly. Read my answer if interested

Answer (score 1):

Using lazy highcharts gem.  Googled for an hour Nothing worked out for me.
Finally I've copied highcharts.js from Vendor directory and pasted it to assets. 
Viola!