# Highcharts not working on Heroku environment, works on local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm using graphs created with Highcharts. They work fine on my local development environment, but on Heroku the graphs are not showing. The div is just empty:

```
<div id="dashboard_chart_75"></div>
```

I'm using the [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem and this is my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require general.js.erb
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require social-share-button
//= require ckeditor-jquery
```

This is the code the generate the chart:

```
spider_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart(polar: true, type: 'line', height: @height)
  f.pane(size: @size)
  f.colors(['#C41D21','#1c77bb'])
  f.xAxis(
    categories: categories.map{ |c| [@survey.id,c.id, c.name] },
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        weight: 'bold',
        width: '100%'
      },
      formatter: %|function() {return '<a href="' + window.location.hostname + '/dashboards/spiders?level=2&survey_id=' + this.value[0] + '&category_id=' + this.value[1] + '">' + this.value[2] + '</a>';}|.js_code }
      )
  f.yAxis(gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon', lineWidth: 0, min: 0, max: 10,tickInterval: 1, tickWidth: 20)
  f.tooltip(enabled: false)
  f.series(name: "Gemiddelde van gewenste score", data: norm_scores, pointPlacement: 'on')
  f.series(name: "Gemiddelde van huidige score", data: current_scores, pointPlacement: 'on')
  f.legend(enabled: @legend, align: 'center', verticalAlign: 'top', y: 10, layout: 'vertical')
end
```

On production I see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined at window.onload
```

Which refers to this line:

```
window.chart_spider_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Please share the code where you create the Highcharts chart.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998902/highcharts-doesnt-work-on-heroku can help

Comment: Nope, already seen that. It seems an assets precompile issue. Normally that is done by Heroku when deploying, but I did it one time manually before deployment. Since then the charts don't work anymore.

Comment: Where is the line `window.chart_spider_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);`? Have you tried removing the formatter, just to test?

Comment: Anything in `public/assets` that has accidentally been committed? You could try to force a Heroku asset recompile by bumping the asset version in `config/production.rb`. E.G changing `config.assets.version = 1.0` to `1.1` and then push.

Comment: Can you share a link to the production site or some sample project we can use? Else it would be hard to asses what could be wrong

Comment: Also check if any of these links helps https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/441, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198568/having-trouble-just-getting-the-highchart-to-show, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990858/highcharts-is-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really seem to be having a simple asset versioning problem, no reason to highcharts to behave differently in production.

Try clearing your assets and forcing precompiling using:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:clobber
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then, add and commit your `public/assets` folder to push into Heroku. I have ran into a lot of trouble trusting that deployment precompile would work as expected. Some times compiling assets gets bugged and you need to change the file before precompiling to perceive a change.

**If that doesn't work**

You may have a problem with the gem in production, maybe it is inside a development block in gemfile, or maybe even `=// require_tree .` or any other require that would possibly insert that code before highcharts lib initializing, messing around with the order of the scripts would help (even though your pasted code doesn't reflect that)

Comment: Hi, I did what you said with the assets precompile, but no luck unfortunately. When I deploy to Heroku, I see it says `Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally`, is that OK? Because normally Heroku takes care of this?

Comment: Yes this is OK, it only means you did what it said: you compiled your assets locally. Assets clobbering clear all files precompiled, including `.sprockets-manifest` which would fix asset versioning problem, have you tryed the second option?

Comment: Your second option did the trick! Both removing `=// require_tree .` completely, or moving it to the bottom helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a `.sprockets-manifest` file in the `public` directory and delete it if found (it's a hidden file). If you compiled the assets locally and accidentally committed that file it can prevent asset compilation on Heroku.

You can also try to force a Heroku asset recompile by bumping the asset version in `config/production.rb`. I.E changing `config.assets.version = 1.0` to `1.1` and then push.

Comment: I did both things you mentioned, no luck. When I look into `public/assets` I would expect to see something like `highcharts.jsxxxxxx`, but I cannot see anything related to highcharts?